# Why is systemd service giving an error on start

Tags: node.js, linux, systemd, directus

I have created a new systemd service and keep getting an error when the service is started and Im not sure what could be up.

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: test-panel.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
```

Here is my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Panel
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/test/panel/
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/npx directus start
Restart=always
RestartSec=500ms
StartLimitInterval=0
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have other services that run just fine when the `ExecStart` is node with a script. Also when im in the active directory and call `npx directus start` manually, everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up changing around how I started Directus by adjusting `ExecStart`.

```
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/node node_modules/directus/dist/start.js
```

This starts the service just like it should and I havent run into any downsides yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add nvm yarn directory into systemd `Environment` option like this:

```ini
[Service]
...
Environment=PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```